# Scipy.optimize.fmin_cg giving TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I am building a oneVsAll classifier in python and using scipy.optimize.fmin_cg to get optimum value of theta vector. This is my classifier function.

```
def oneVsAll(X, y, K, reg_parameter):
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((X.shape[0],1)), X))
    theta = initialiseTheta((K,X.shape[1]))
    print(theta[0].shape)
    for i in range(K):
        print("In for loop")
        digit_class = i if i else 10
        theta[i] = opt.fmin_cg(f = lrCostFunction, fprime=None, x0=theta[i], args = (X, (y==digit_class).flatten() , reg_parameter), maxiter=50)

    return theta
```

This is my cost function

```
def lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, reg_parameter):
    m = y.shape[0]  #number of training examples
    J =0
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)
    Z = np.dot(X, theta)
    print("Z shape", Z.shape)
    hx = sigmoid(Z)
    print("hx - y shape", (hx-y).shape)
    print("X shape",(X[:,0].T).shape )
    print("dot product shape", np.dot(X[:,0].T, (hx -y)))
    J = -(1/m)*(np.sum(np.multiply(y, np.log(hx)) + np.multiply((1-y), np.log(1-hx)))) + (reg_parameter/(2*m))*(np.sum(np.power(theta[1:], 2)))
    grad_unregularized = (1/m)*(np.dot(X[:,1:].T, (hx -y)))
    grad[0] = (1/m)*(np.dot(X[:,0].T, (hx -y)))
    grad[1:] = grad_unregularized + (reg_parameter/m)*(theta[1:])

    return (J, grad)
```

Comment: From reading documentation I don't think you can return the gradient together with the function value in f. But it looks like you can get around using minimize: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: There's a `fprime` parameter that takes a grad function.  Why aren't you using that?

Comment: While I think the `(J,grad)` guess is reasonable, you really should provide more information when asking about errors.  The traceback, for example, so we can see where it is trying to subtract one tuple from another.  If you are unwilling to provide that, then you should provide enough data variables so that we can copy-n-paste your code, and run it ourselves.